# Docker Kubernetes Container Dependeny

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am new to Docker and Kubernetes and I am attempting to wrap my head around all of this.

I am setting up a Console application for Linux as a test concept that I need to be able to have a dependency on another container, that will ensure that the other container is deployed alongside the console application container.  Basically, I am trying to add a dependency on the gdal container so that I can ensure it is deployed alongside my console application so that I can run basic gdal commands from a bash prompt.

Right now, I've added orchestrator support for Kubernetes and it has created my azds.yaml file along with the charts folders and configurations.  From what I've been able to piece together, I believe I need to add this dependency to the values.yaml of the chart for the console application?  Or does it just go under a dependencies heading in the Chart.yaml?  What would be the syntax to do this for a pre-existing container image that is online?

The default template through a ton of stuff in both the azds.yaml and the Chart.yaml, and I'm just trying to make heads or tails of all of this.  Any guidance or resources that would help explain this in a bit more detail would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Console application" and "bash prompt" aren't really good fits for Kubernetes; it's a much better match for server-type applications that don't need operator intervention, and where you can run multiple copies of the same application for scale and redundancy.

Comment: @DavidMaze My end goal was going to run a web server with endpoints that process the user inputs, then performs GDAL based operations images it retrieves.  The problem is, I need those endpoints to run the GDAL commands, which are typically ran/executed via cmd line and/or bin/bash.

I was hoping, as part of my container, I could get the python and GDAL environments installed and setup, so I could use run the command line commands to fire of the GDAL libraries or execute a python script I made.  I simply just boxed it in a console app for testing purposes.

Comment: If the GDAL tools/libraries are built into your image (as in your other question) then your Web server can call the subprocess/functions, just as though you weren't in a container.  A CLI-based setup might make sense for some early prototyping in plain Docker, but it'll be tricky to make it run well in Kubernetes.